# Pairing inputted names to previously stored names

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this table.

**Names**

Two fields, ID and Names. Example data would be 1 | Harry.

Now what i am planning on doing is that if someone enters in something like Henry in my form, it will search my database for a result that begins with "H" Then if their are multiple results, it will see if there are any results that are "He" if their isn't it will fallback to the previous result from "H".

The only thing i can think of doing is this,

```
$inputted_name = "Henry";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `names`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $stored_name = $row['name'];
    if($stored_name[0] == $inputted_name[0]){
        if($stored_name[1] == $inputted_name[1]){
            $result = $stored_name;
            break;
        }   else   {
            // continue looking but then return the first result that matched one letter?
        }
    }
}
```

Now i am sure this can't be the best way to do it. Would it be possible in a query? I'm just really not sure where to look for a sensible answer for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 
    mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `names`");

to 
    mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `names` WHERE NAME='".$inputted_name."'");

and check you have more than one answer.

Note this is a bad way to do it if your name comes from a non controlled source, such as a web page, as it would allow a SQL injection, and then you would need parameters, but for your example it would work.

Edit: Now I read your question again, yes, you would need parameters or escaping such as:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($inputted_name);
mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `names` WHERE NAME='".$=name."'");
```

Also, don't try and do in code what the database can do easily (like search for characters). Your code is almost always going to be worse than the database for doing a search, leave it to the database.

Comment: But it won't be the exact name. I want it to match the first letter. e.g For Henry, search for He, then if no results search for H.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, you want it to always match the first two letters, then if not match the 1st? So if you enter 'Paul' it will match 'Pamela' first?

Comment: Exactly, search for the first two letters to match, if there is no result, search for the first letter only.

Comment: Then it depends on your data. If you have only 10 - 100 names, just do a search for the first letter, and look in a loop, otherwise, just trim your name down to two characters, do an sql search for 'SELECT `name` FROM `names` WHERE NAME LIKE '".$left_of_name."%'

Comment: The names will be around 400. Also won't WHERE NAME LIKE mean it will match "so" with "jason"? Im only trying to match the first two letters.

Comment: no, it depends on the wildcard, so if you trim the name down to the two letters and add the wildcard, as search like 'SELECT Name from Names WHERE Name LIKE 'pa%' will find Paul and Paula, but not Hepa as it is two letters then anything. To find Hepa you would need 'LIKE %pa%'